# Creating PHP function with respect to syntax

Tags: php, oop

I didn't know how to put the question.

I know I can create a function like

```
function abc($type, $value)
{
    //TO DO 
}
```

and use it like

```
abc('name','superman');
```

But I want to have a function that would result in syntax like

```
$name->validate('length', 10);
```

Now how do I achieve this kind of syntax and create a function `validate` that would support this syntax. Also I work in Laravel if anyone can help would be appreciated.

Comment: What would this validate *method* do exactly? As you can see, this is *object oriented* programming, not regular procedural programming. So whatever class `$name` is, this needs to be a method in that class.

Comment: [object oriented in php](http://php.net/oop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @hassan and @Qirel said this is Object Oriented Programming.

You have to create class and then methods in it.

Then you can call it by ->